# How to load an image based on height of the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have two images: `A.png` and `B.png`

I am trying to load the images based on device resolution

I mean if the page is being loaded on desktop A.png must be loaded
or if it is being loaded on iPhone B.png must be loaded.

**Javascript:**

```
var heights = $(window).height(); 
if (heights < 500) {
    // load B.png
}
else {
    // load A.png
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions to make this possible?

I am using codeigniter.

many thanks.

**UPDATE**
Here is the logic i used

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
{
img.bannerimage{background:url(<?=base_url();?>mbanner/<?=$mbanner?>);} 
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px)

{
img.bannerimage{background : url(<?=base_url();?>uploads/<?=$bannerimage?>);}
}
```

But no success
(I am not good at css),

Comment: Your question looks like it answered itself. Do you just not know how to fetch and serve images via js? If so, look into $.ajax... and I guess ANY DOM manipulation or css updating in the success method.

Comment: Out of curiosity though - why are you not just using css media queries?

Comment: Are you more interested in the size of browser window, or whether the device is a PC or an iphone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can find width/height of desktop/mobile browsers':

```
var height = window.innerHeight || $(window).height();
var width = window.innerWidth || $(window).width();
var img = new Image();
if (height > 500) {
    img.src = '/a.png';
} else {
    img.src = '/b.png'
}
$('body').append(img);
```